# How to interpret types reported by GHCI

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

When asking `GHCI` for a type, I tend to get far from ideal types (e.g. not exactly the thing to put into my function signatures or syntactically similar to documented types of library combinators).

```
*Main Control.Monad.Shell> :t script
script :: Script f -> text-1.2.1.3:Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text

*Main Control.Monad.Shell> :t cmd "echo" "foo"
cmd "echo" "foo" :: CmdParams t => t
```

Why does `GHCI` show a hidden, internal type (and even package version), but in second case a general type when package was (probably) designed to work with an alias?

Is it good practice to basically avoid type inferencer with non-trivial types and lookup documentation instead?

A more "popular" library example:

```
*Main Control.Lens> :t _2
_2 :: (Functor f, Field2 s t a b) => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
*Main Control.Lens> :t over
over :: Profunctor p => Setting p s t a b -> p a b -> s -> t
*Main Control.Lens> :t over _2
over _2 :: Field2 s t a b => (a -> b) -> s -> t
```

Comment: `lens` can be bad about this, and often its documentation helpfully lists several alternative simpler types to give intuition. Other than looking at documentation, my tip is to use `:i` rather than `:t` for library identifiers, then you get the actual written type signature, which is sometimes less expanded.

Comment: Yeah, most of the things in `lens` in particular are more easily understood as "you can choose this to be any one of this family of types", rather than the "real" type that manages to unify all of them. Uninformative `:type` results is just something you have to live with to use `lens`, unless/until you actually learn a lot more of the theory underpinning its construction (which is otherwise unnecessary to use it effectively).

Comment: Regarding "Is it good practice to basically avoid type inferencer with non-trivial types and lookup documentation instead?", it's not a matter of "good practice". I would expect most people use whichever is more helpful/convenient at the time, without worrying about either option being "better". I use the interpreter a lot while developing, so I will often start with `:t` if I happen to have a ghci session going. If that doesn't help (possibly because the type is confusing, but often because the type alone isn't a complete description of what the thing does), I look up the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How ghci describes the type depends on:

1. Is the referenced module in scope?
2. Is the referenced package part of your cabal project?

Here's a situation where you will see an internal type instead of the expected exported type:

```
=== file B.hs ===

module B (hello) where
import Data.Text
hello = pack "Hello, world"

=== file A.hs ===
module A where
import B
```

and then running `ghci A.hs` and the command `:t hello` will report:

```
ghci> :t hello
hello :: Data.Text.Internal.Text
```

However, if module A imports Data.Text:

```
module A where
import B
import Data.Text
```

then ghci responds to the type inquiry with:

```
ghci> :t hello
hello :: Text
```

As for the specific package name appearing in the type's name, that can occur if `text` is not explicitly mentioned as a dependency in your cabal file, but you import a Data.Text value from another package.

For example, suppose the module B above was part of the `hello` package, and module A part of a separate package, say `uses-hello`.

Let's say the `uses-hello.cabal` file looks like:

```
=== file uses-hello.cabal ===
...
library:
  exposed-modules: A
  build-depends: base, hello
...
```

Note that `uses-hello` does *not* list `text` as a package dependency, but it can use a Text value by importing `B` from the `hello` package. If you run `cabal repl` in the `uses-hello` package you will get output like this:

```
$ cabal repl
*A> :t hello
hello :: text-1.2.1.1:Data.Text.Internal.Text
```